# How to define child's specific style or script for a HTML page which extends a parent/base.html

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, extends

This is a Django project where I have a base.html with a defined outline for the whole project and other pages extend base.html and have their own content. I need to code js script for events happening in child pages in child.html page itself, but the code works only when I define the script in parent's header,Is there any way to achieve this?

base.html

```
 <html lang="en">
   <head>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 

     <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").keydown(function(){
         $("input").css("background-color", "yellow");
         });
      });
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 {% block content%}

 {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

child.html

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
   **<!--
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input").keydown(function(){
         $("input").css("background-color", "yellow");
         });
      });
    </script> 
   -->**

 {% block content %}
  Enter your name: <input type="text">
 {% endblock %}
```

I am just trying to change bg color on keyup, but when I define the JS code in child.html it doesn't work

Comment: What happens when you add a `<style>` or `<script>` to the child page? How does it end up in the browser? I have a hard time believing it gets completely ignored or removed.

Comment: Writing the script inside the "block content" works.